# Periscope (by Twitter) comments feed – how to retrieve viewer messages to my script?

Tags: reverse-engineering

I want to build some automation based on comments by viewers of my live  Periscope broadcast.

There is no public API for that.  Maybe there is some private API feature I could use for now?

Comment: Have you had any progress on this? Since the comments are also visible when logged out, I believe comment feed is also part of some public API. However, I'm not able to figure out which one it is. Have you had any success?

Comment: No progress so far : (